# How to use KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN to obtain the a key from the KMS but I haven't figured out how to generate the first_level_keyset correctly. I'm getting the following message:

**AEAD.ENCRYPT failed: Keyset deserialization failed: Error reading keyset data: Could not parse the input stream as a Keyset-proto.**

I'm following the doc:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions#keyskeyset_chain

My code:

```
DECLARE KMS_RESOURCE_NAME STRING;
DECLARE FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET BYTES;

SET KMS_RESOURCE_NAME = 'gcp-kms://projects/XXX/locations/XXX/keyRings/XXX-key-ring/cryptoKeys/XXX-key';
SET FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET = FROM_HEX("0a240... <suppressed>");

select AEAD.ENCRYPT(KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(KMS_RESOURCE_NAME, FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET), b'string to encrypt', b'customer_id');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the `first_level_keyset`, you will need to:

1.-Create a [`Key Management Service`](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/quickstart). Users need to have the [`cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypterViaDelegation` role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).

2.-Create a raw keyset.You need to execute the next command at cloud shell:

```
bq --project_id=my_project query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') AS raw_keyset"
```

This command is going to return the raw keyset.

3.-Create and format a wrapped keyset.

```
echo "CK3245gBE...    <suppressed>..." |base64 --decode > /tmp/decoded_key

gcloud kms encrypt --plaintext-file=/tmp/decoded_key --key=projects/my_project/locations/my_location/keyRings/my_keyring/cryptoKeys/my_key --ciphertext-file=/tmp/bankaccounts_wrapped

od -An --format=o1 /tmp/bankaccounts_wrapped |tr -d '\n'|tr ' ' '\'
```

This is going to return the array of bytes that you need to set at the `first_level_keyset`, such as:

```
DECLARE KMS_RESOURCE_NAME STRING;
DECLARE FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET BYTES;
 
SET KMS_RESOURCE_NAME = 'gcp-kms://projects/my_project/locations/my_location/keyRings/my_keyring/cryptoKeys/my_key';
SET FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET = b'\012\044\000\150\267\053\201 <suppressed>';
 
select AEAD.ENCRYPT(KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(KMS_RESOURCE_NAME, FIRST_LEVEL_KEYSET), b'string to encrypt', b'customer_id');
```

The result of this:

[image]

Comment: @Edmilson Santana does this answer help you?

Comment: This helped me a lot. But I had to realize how to simulate the od command on windows because I had no linux/mac available.

Comment: Thanks @EdmilsonSantana and @JoseGutierrezPaliza it helped me a lot!
Also if you get this warning `tr: warning: an unescaped backslash at end of string is not portable` using `tr` command combined with `od` just escape the last backslash to fix. Like this: `od -An --format=o1 your-key-name | tr -d '\n' | tr ' ' '\\'`